# PHP keyword to convert decimal number into a number always one ahead

Tags: php

```
$val=3.1;
echo $val;
```

How can i get the result 4 from $val.

Comment: you can use `echo ceil($val);`  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php

Answer (score 2):

Use `ceil`

```
<?php
echo ceil(4.3);    // 5
echo ceil(9.999);  // 10
echo ceil(-3.14);  // -3
?>
```

Reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php

Answer (score 1):

[Ceil function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) is what you want. Just do the following

```
ceil($val);
```

P.S. if you want it to be always an integer number that is bigger by 1 than the previous (even if the number is Integer), you can do something like this:

```
$a = ( ceil($val) == $val) ? ($val + 1) : ceil($val);
```

Comment: To be strictly accurate, the *type* of the result of `ceil` is `float`, so a cast is required to return an integer.

Comment: @Hamish thanks, I knew something might be fishy here with strict comparison. Changed it.